# In Haunt #43 - The Star Sickness, does any use of the serum on a traitor kill them?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

For those not familiar with this Haunt, a found a general description of [Haunt #43 — The Star Sickness](http://betrayalhouse.tumblr.com/Haunt), (although sadly not the exact rule text, so if someone has the rules handy please update).

We played this haunt the other day and interpreted the rules to mean that a traitor was only killed by the serum when it was injected in them by an Alien, because the rule stating they were killed by the serum were in the Alien section of the Haunt description. Thus when a traitor was immunized by a player we assumed it had no effect. But as we played it out, this didn't seem to make sense.

From the link above, it appears the correct interpretation is that when a traitor is injected for any reason they die, and when a player is injected they are cured.

However, this didn't make sense to us either because then a traitor would have to reveal themselves as such when someone wanted to "cure" them. Or is this how it is supposed to work? The best way to root out traitors is to try and cure them?

Comment: Haunt 43 has a different tile according to the WotC pdf, [Survivor](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_SurvivalRev_120105.pdf) and Traitor [43 -- A Gathering of Shadows](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_TraitorRev_120105.pdf)

Comment: @user1873 Interesting, but obviously we were playing a different version of the rules—perhaps because this haunt, although fun, was confusing and had a lot of rules. The object that came up was the Spear, and I read through all the spear-triggered haunts in the links you provided and none were the same.

Comment: @AdamWuerl The revised survivor's and traitor's books feature a few haunts that were completely replaced like this one (8 in total - haunts 17, 18, 19, 31, 33, 34, 43, 50). It is worth printing out a copy of the newer books to use, although using the older iterations as well gives you more haunts to choose from as they are still usable.

Comment: @winterblood Thanks for letting me know. It was a friend's game and he hadn't played in a while, so I don't think any of us knew that some of the haunts had been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the best way to determine if someone is a traitor is to (attempt to) inject them with the serum.

If they are a traitor they are killed by agreeing to the serum, and if they are not a traitor it completely absolves them of any current or future suspicion, plus heals them back to their starting values and stops them potentially taking damage each turn from the physical attack that occurs on the haunt revealer's turn (this is not directly stated, but is implied by the rules).

If they refuse, you then have a fairly good idea that they are a traitor, after which they can then do their best to infect you, or die by other means and become an alien.

As for your confusion over the serum, any explorer can use it, but it would mostly be pointless for a traitor to (the only good case I can think of for a traitor using the serum on another explorer is to redirect suspicion).

Note that on becoming an alien the explorer drops all items and that aliens cannot trade items. This seems to indicate a general **intent** in the rules for aliens to not be able to use items, but it also specifically says that aliens are treated as monsters only for the purposes of movement and taking damage, thus rules-as-read they are not technically prevented from later picking up or stealing items.